# Access violation when using ActiveX control within WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, crash, activex

I'm trying to embed an ActiveX control (Sax Basic IDE) in a WPF window, using an auto-generated WinForms wrapper DLL and a `WindowsFormsHost`. This worked a few months ago, on a different computer. But now the control throws a native exception, “Access violation executing location…”

I see this exception when trying the following:

1. Adding the control to the toolbox (via the COM Components tab) and dropping it onto a Windows Forms user control. Visual Studio crashes. I get the above exception if I debug using another instance of Visual Studio.
2. Instantiating the control in code and attaching it directly to a `WindowsFormsHost`:

   ```
   private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       SaxHost.Child = new AxSb6ent.AxBasicIdeCtl();
   }
   ```

   When I launch this window, the application crashes with the above exception, on the `SaxHost.Child = …` line.
3. Instantiating the control in code and calling `CreateControl()`:

   ```
   private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       var ctl = new AxSb6ent.AxBasicIdeCtl();
       ctl.CreateControl();
       SaxHost.Child = ctl;
   }
   ```

   When I launch this window, the application crashes with the above exception, on the `CreateControl()` line.

How can I get to the bottom of these crashes and make the ActiveX control play nice?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that maybe the ActiveX control is 32 bit and you compiling in 64 bit or something like that (or vice versa)?  Just a shot in the dark.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I've just double-checked that everything is set to build 32-bit only, and it is. Thanks, though.